# Where to learn AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Yes, I know that there are some similar questions here, but they do not the same as mine.

I know about such a great resources such as code-school and code-academy where you may get some PHP and JS skills via coding right inside the website.

But is there any similar thing to learn AJAX? I am familiar with JS and with jQuery as well, but would like to learn AJAX too.

I want to learn AJAX especially for interacting with PHP (I am familiar with PHP too).

Comment: you want to learn from free source or paid source ?

Comment: Best for me at the moment is free. But paid could be considered as a reserve.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/

Comment: it is easy just google it.

Comment: @SohilDesai but google relevance != programmers experience

Comment: search the same in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery provides a great library for [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

AJAX is basically a way to make http request with some transparency (the page won't reload) you'll have to treat the result of the request with javascript.

One good thing coming on are websockets, which, basically, allow requests to go both ways.

Answer (score 1):

use the following site for learn basics of ajax

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't miss [HTML5Rocks tutorial about XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) which contains advanced AJAX techniques like upload and progress handling.

Answer (score 0):

Good starting point is, as always, MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest